# Show that the set of connectives $\{+, \wedge\}$ is not complete, where $+$ is logical XOR

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove these using semantics. According to the textbook, to show that it is not complete, we need to show that any formal $\alpha$is tautologically implied by the sentence $X$, where $\alpha$ is formed by $X$ and the given logical connectives.

1. If $\alpha$ is a sentence symbol, then clearly $X \models X$
2. If $\alpha = \beta \wedge \gamma$, and by inductive hypothesis $X \models \beta$, $X \models \gamma$, then $X \models \beta \wedge \gamma = \alpha$

Now, this is my first doubt

3. If $\alpha = \beta + \gamma$, and by inductive hypothesis $X \models \beta$, $X \models \gamma$, then $X \models \alpha $

How is this statement correct? If $X$ is true, then $\beta$ is true and $\gamma$ is true, then $\beta + \gamma$ is false when $X$ is true so clearly $X \not \models \beta + \gamma$

My second doubt is, even if we assume the last statement is true, how is this proving the set is incomplete? $X$ entails $\alpha$, that is all we know. There is no case where $\alpha$ is false and $X$ is true, so $\alpha$ is tautologically implied by $X$. The textbook says we cannot derive $\neg \alpha$, hence the set is incomplete. I don't understand how this conclusion was derived. Can I get a good explanation for this?

Comment: Hint: prove that if the value of all variables is set to false, any expression you can build with $+$ and $\land$ evaluates to false.

Comment: @MarkSaving yes that would be because $\neg \alpha$ not existing right? But how have they concluded that $\neg \alpha$ does not exist. Also statement 3 is given as true in the book but I am not very sure about its validity

Comment: No, the argument goes the other way. First, we conclude that for any expression we can write, if we plug in False for all variables, we get False. From this, we conclude that we cannot write anything logically equivalent to $\neg \alpha$, since $\neg \alpha$ doesn’t have this property.

Comment: @MarkSaving Oh you mean both $\beta \wedge \gamma$ and $\beta + \gamma$ evaluate to F when both $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are F. So $\neg \alpha $ cannot be made from the given logical connectives since if its constituent variables are all false, we must get a T. Did I get that right?

Comment: @MarkSaving also I am concerned about the terminology used in the proof such as  X entailing $\alpha$. The proof proved that $X \models \alpha$ always, so when $X$ is true, $\alpha$ is also true (ie tautologically implied by X). So we can never have an $\alpha$ that is false when the sentence symbol $X$ is true. Is my interpretation correct?